# Is it possible to include sound sharing from multiple Pc`s to a designated Pc ?

Tags: audio, synergy

Often when you are working using multiple Computers is great with Synergy, but not beeing able to hear the sound of the other Computers can sometimes drive you insane (You have to unplug and replug your headphones constantly, crawling under your desk). Is it possible to include a feature which connects all Computer`s audio into a designated output PC ?
Love your Software

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

It does require a few things though.

- The output pc must have a soundcard capable of playing over the speakers what comes into the line-in port.
- The output pc must have a line-in port
- Cables and splitters to connect all other pc's with this pc.

But if you go this route, its probably a better idea to connect all pc's directly to the speaker using splitters. That way the main pc does not even have to be turned on for audio to work.

Here's an example of what you could use, depending on how many pc's you need to connect:

[8 Way Mini splitter:

[image]](https://www.dv247.com/studio-equipment/morgan-acoustics-8-way-mini-splitter--62441)